# Regex for IP after DST= but not after SRC=

Tags: regex

I'm searching for a special Regex, that recognizes an IP Adresses after a certain string.

That's the regex for the IP

```
(([2]([0-4][0-9]|[5][0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])[.]){3}(([2]([0-4][0-9]|[5][0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]))
```

The IP follows in my log to

DST=192.168.1.1

Which Regex do i need to just select a IP after DST= but not after SRC=

Comment: ...have you tried sticking `DST=` in the front of the IP regex? Sometimes the simplest solution is the correct one :-)

Comment: yes, sure :) but i just wanna mark the ipadress not also the string dst=

Comment: @zordache: I'm using multitail. Tried your regex but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the problem is it finds
>   DST=192.168.1.1 but it should only
>   find 192.168.1.1

It depends a lot on the tool you use.  For example with sed this might give you want you want.

```
echo "... SRC=10.1.1.1 DST=192.168.1.1 LEN=40 ..."  | \
sed -e 's/.*DST=\([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\).*/\1/g'

192.168.1.1
```

See this article about [regex grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

If you are trying to do highlighting this looks like what you may want/need.  From the [configuration](http://github.com/avar/linode-etc/blob/master/multitail.conf).

```
# cs_re_s:<color>:<regular expression>
#             Like cs_re but only the substrings are used(!). E.g.:
#             ^....(...)...(...)
#             In the example above only what matches between '(' and ')' is
#             assigned a color. See the 'acctail' colorscheme for an example.
```

There is even an example that in that file close to what I believe you want.  The example is `cs_re_s:cyan:kernel: .*(SRC=[^ ]*) *(DST=[^ ]*)`  What you want which I think is to highlight anything following a DST may be `cs_re_s:red:kernel: .*DST=([^ ]*)`.

Comment: it doesn't work for multitail, gives me an error in regex - invalid back reference

Comment: Great zoredache, muchas Gracias, it works, your help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
DST=(([2]([0-4][0-9]|[5][0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])[.]){3}(([2]([0-4][0-9]|[5][0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]))
```

Comment: the problem is it finds DST=192.168.1.1 but it should only find 192.168.1.1. i'm searching for an expression that just finds the ip after DST=

Comment: the braces should put the ip address into $1, $2, ...

Comment: No the braces do pattern repeating. I think you mean "parentheses".

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with lookbehind expression.

`regex_test.txt` content:

```
DST=192.168.1.1
SRC=192.168.1.1
```

then from command line:

```
   grep -P '(?<=DST=)(([2]([0-4][0-9]|[5][0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])[.]){3}(([2]([0-4][0-9]|[5][0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]))' regex_test.txt
```

output:

```
DST=192.168.1.1
```

**Edit**

```
grep -Po '(?<=DST=)(([2]([0-4][0-9]|[5][0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])[.]){3}(([2]([0-4][0-9]|[5][0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]))' regex_test.txt
```

output:

```
192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Change the `-P` to `-Po` to output only the IP address.

Comment: You are right. My output statement does not state that it matches only IP. On my terminal `DST=` is green and `192.168.1.1` is red so it is obvious.